# R devtools::release() Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, package, devtools

Using devtools::release() to release a package I have a problem with the section that uses devtools::check() to make sure the package builds correctly.

Using the package code hosted on gihtub at https://github.com/RobWHickman/ggparliament. Had the same error on a variety of windows machines. Haven't had the chance to check on linux yet.

The error I get after passing the spelling check section of devtools::release is (the package name is ggparliament, the paths themselves have been edited here but are correct):

```
Is documentation free of spelling errors? (you can ignore false positives)
1: Yes
2: No way
3: Nope

Selection: 1
Building and checking ggparliament ==================================================================================================

Updating ggparliament documentation

Loading ggparliament

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[11]="C:\Users\my\path\ggparliament/R/draw_majoritythreshold.R    ": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[11]="C:\Users\my\path\ggparliament\R\draw_majoritythreshold.R    ": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

3: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\my\path\ggparliament\R': Permission denied
```

As I mentioned, when checking the package with devtools::check() I got the same error, though it worked if I used the rstudio shortcut Ctrl+Shift+E which I believe does the same thing.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: yup https://github.com/RobWHickman/ggparliament just building for CRAN submission

Comment: When you ran `devtools::check()` and `devtools::release()`, was it done like that (i.e., no overriding argument defaults), or was it done in a manner similar to `devtools::check("path/to/ggparliament")`?

Comment: ran with no arguments. Also just checked with `devtools::check("C:/full/path/to/package/ggparliament")` and it gave the same error

Comment: Does `full/path/to/package` have any spaces? If so, it might be related to [this issue filed on GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1864)

Comment: pretty sure not on any of the machines I've tried. The current one Im on is
`C:\Users\Alaa\Desktop\ggparliament` (copied direct from windows file explorer hence reversed slashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried checking your package using `devtools::check()`,<sup>1</sup> I ran into the same error. After using `debug(devtools::check)`, I was able to determine the error came when `check()` called `document()`, and then in turn that the error from `document()` was caused when it called `roxygenise()`. It appears there was a bug in `roxygen2` that was fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/791) (you can see the related issue [here](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/790)). After I installed the development version of `roxygen2` via

```
devtools::install_github("klutometis/roxygen")
```

I no longer got that error from running `devtools::check()`; it appeared that the documentation was proceeding correctly. However, once it started to create the vignettes, I got a different error:

```
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Quitting from lines 43-60 (arrange_parliament_8.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'arrange_parliament_8.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
Evaluation error: argument "x" is missing, with no default.
```

So you may need to check through your vignettes, though it seems to be an unrelated issue.

---

<sub>1. Your question notes you haven't been able to try on a Linux system. My attempts were on a computer running Ubuntu 16.04.</sub>